# Why is setting a .text property messing with NSTimers

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm programming a game in xcode 7 using swift and it is an endless game where you avoid falling objects. I have an NSTimer:

```
@IBAction func startNow(sender: UIButton) {
    player.center.x = 160
    explosion.center.x = 1000
    explosion.center.y = 1000
    for f in r {
        random = Int(arc4random_uniform(350))
        f.image = UIImage(named: "blueSQ1")
        if random == 20 {
            f.image = UIImage(named: "moneyRain")
        }
    }
    random1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
    if random1 <= 3 {
        r10.image = UIImage(named: "blackSQ1")
    }
    slider.value = Float(player.center.x + 122)
    shieldImg.image = UIImage(named: "nil")
    ad = 1.5
    moveDown.invalidate()
    speed1 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed2 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed3 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed4 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed5 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed6 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed7 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed8 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed9 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed10 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed11 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed12 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed13 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed14 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    speed15 = ad + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
    for x in r {
        x.center.y = 55
        x.center.x = CGFloat(20+arc4random_uniform(285))
    }

    moveDown = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.015, target:self, selector: Selector("updatePos"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timeyWimey = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target:self, selector: Selector("incrementTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    checkShield = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target:self, selector: Selector("ifShielded"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func incrementTime() {
    timer+=0.1
    scoreProgress.setProgress(Float(timer/highscore), animated: false)
    //time.text = "Time: \(timer)"
}
func updatePos() {
    start.center.y = 10000
    startOut.center.y = 10000
    coinsLabel.center.y = 10000
    buyShieldOut.center.y = 10000
    ifDone()
    r1.center.y += speed1
    r2.center.y += speed2
    r3.center.y += speed3
    r4.center.y += speed4
    r5.center.y += speed5
    r6.center.y += speed6
    r7.center.y += speed7
    r8.center.y += speed8
    r9.center.y += speed9
    r10.center.y += speed10
    r11.center.y += speed11
    r12.center.y += speed12
    r13.center.y += speed13
    r14.center.y += speed14
    r15.center.y += speed15
    for q in r {
        if ((q.center.x)+3 > player.center.x - 15) && ((q.center.x)-3 < player.center.x + 15) && ((q.center.y)+3 > player.center.y - 15) && ((q.center.y)-3 < player.center.y + 15)
        {
            if (shield == 0) && ((q.image == UIImage(named: "blueSQ1")) || (q.image == UIImage(named: "blackSQ1")))
            {
                explosion.center.y = 10000
                explosion.center.x = 10000
                start.text = "RESTART"
                start.center.y = 289
                timeyWimey.invalidate()
                y = Float(round(10*timer)/10)
                timeOut.text = "Previous time: \(y)"
                coins += Int(y*10)
                coinsLabel.text = "Coins: \(coins)"
                if y > highscore {
                    highscore = y
                }
                highTime.text = "Best time: \(highscore)"
                startOut.center.y = 289
                coinsLabel.center.y = 130
                buyShieldOut.center.y = 167
                moveDown.invalidate()
                timer = 0
            }
            if shield == 1 && q.image == UIImage(named: "blueSQ1")
            {
                activated = true
            }
            if q.image == UIImage(named: "moneyRain") {
                coins += 500
                q.image = UIImage(named: "whiteSQ")
            }
            if q.image == UIImage(named: "green2") {

            }
        }
    }
    if ((explosion.center.x)+18 > player.center.x - 15) && ((explosion.center.x)-18 < player.center.x + 15) {
            if shield == 1
            {
                shield = 0
                activated = false
            }
            start.text = "RESTART"
            start.center.y = 289
            timeyWimey.invalidate()
            y = Float(round(10*timer)/10)
            timeOut.text = "Previous time: \(y)"
            coins += Int(y*10)
            coinsLabel.text = "Coins: \(coins)"
            if y > highscore {
                highscore = y
            }
            highTime.text = "Best time: \(highscore)"
            startOut.center.y = 289
            coinsLabel.center.y = 130
            buyShieldOut.center.y = 167
            moveDown.invalidate()
            explosion.center = player.center
            timer = 0

    }


}
```

This works fine. But I have commented out the time.text line as when it is active the falling objects repeatedly go back to the top of the screen and begin falling again, then go back to the top of the screen again etc. very quickly - a fraction of a second. It seems to make no sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no code here that shows any items moving on screen. Without information it's pretty hard to work out what is causing the problem.

Comment: You'll need to post more.  I'm assuming that "time" references a label on the screen that displays how long you've been avoiding the objects, but other than that, this is such a small snippet of code that I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Hopefully this should be enough to work it out. Sorry for the lack of code. @Fogmeister

Comment: see above @CodeMark22